# Can't run pytest with tmpdir: "AttributeError: module 'py' has no attribute 'path'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I installed pytest via `pip install pytest` then ran the following simple test:

```
def test_sf_bayer_training(tmpdir):
    print(tmpdir)
    _config = TestingTrainerConfigInstance()
    _config.name = 'test_sf_bayer_training'
    _config.output_path = tmpdir / _config.name
    _curr_p = os.getcwd()
    _config.model_config_path = f'.models/sf.yaml'
    print(_config)
    return
```

I received the following error:

```
  File "/home/davids/venvs/vai/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/_io/terminalwriter.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _pytest.compat import final
  File "/home/davids/venvs/vai/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/compat.py", line 44, in <module>
    LEGACY_PATH = py.path. local
AttributeError: module 'py' has no attribute 'path'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I check locally:

```
(vai) ➜  ~ ipython
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import py

In [2]: py.path. local
Out[2]: py._path.local.LocalPath
```

How can I solve the issue with pytest so it can run?

My pytest package:

```
py==1.11.0
pytest==7.4.0
```

Comment: What OS are you on? And did you install `py` package manually? Because I think pytest 7.4.0 ships with its own `py.py` module (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/7.4.0/src/py.py) which has `py.path` (https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/tree/7.4.0/src/_pytest/_py)

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Just to make your example more minimal and to rule-out if it's related to your `TestingTrainerConfigInstance`, what happens if your test function simply contains `print(tmpdir)` and `print(tmpdir/"foo.config")`. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Does `pip uninstall -y py` fix it? Probably py==1.11.0 installation is shadowing pytest's own py shim.

Comment: @wim uninstall directly didn't solve it. but it was overshadowing solved by creating a brand new env

Comment: @GinoMempin it didn't work with that :\

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that apperantly there was a `py` module that overshadowed the interal usage of `pytest` which caused the error.

I solved it by recreating my environment with the minimal requirments to activate `pytest`.

Answer (score 1):

You're on pytest 7.x, please use [`tmp_path`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/reference/reference.html#tmp-path) fixture instead, which returns a stdlib [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) instance. The `tmpdir` fixture is legacy.

The basic usage shown in your question is the same, so you can just find/replace `tmpdir` with `tmp_path` in this code.

Comment: True that this is old, but this was not the cause of the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had pytest 7.x installed, but pytest-benchmark was still at 3.4.x. Upgrading pytest-benchmark to 4.0.0 fixed the issue.